# Devexpress.XtraEditors.checkedcomboboxedit OK/Cancel is moved to top when the system resolution is changed

Tags: winforms, devexpress

[image]

Recently I have migrated my application to DevExpress15.2.9. While testing in laptop i observed that Devexpress.XtraEditors.checkedcomboboxedit Ok/Cancel buttons are displaying on top instead of bottom.This is happening with less resolution.Do we have any properties to make it stable even if resolution is changed.

Answer (score 0):

If you need you can dynamically reset the resolution, and arrange the control according to that resolution..
But if u use WPF it will avoid the resolution problem.